# Is it possible to use service worker to show notifications when user is on website?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I have a website where I register a service worker for push notifications. There are two cases to show an upcoming notification :

- the user is not on the website but the browser is up: the **service worker** handles the event and show the notifications.
- the user is on the website: the **website** handles the event of receiving the notification and shows it.

Can service worker **always** handle the event, even when the user is on the website? If it's possible how to do so?

This with the purpose of not adding an event handler to each of my website pages.

Thanks in advance for any clarification,

Comment: A service worker, works on the background. Even if the user is not on the page. I don't think the service worker will fire the event if the user is on the website because I have no experience with that. Have you considered to read the [service workers documentation?](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/)

Comment: A service worker runs in a background thread of a browser, which runs as long as the conputer runs. The webworker and the webpage can communicate via messages, so the webworker could try to redirect a message to the webpage, and if the webpage does not answer, then handle it by himself

Comment: @Variable thanks for the reply, I'll look the link you gave me, but from previous research, I couldn't find that particular case :/

Comment: @JonasW. i don't need to redirect the push notifications from my service worker to my website, but just the service worker to handle it every time, even when the user is on the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an anwser there : https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications#handling_the_push_event_in_the_service_worker

The `push event` is the event that the service worker needs to handle in order to show a push notification afterwards.

By doing so, even when the webapp is on focus or not, the service worker will "see" the push message.

Answer (score 1):

> Can service worker always handle the event, even when the user is on the website?

Yes, they run regardless of the currently opened pages of the browser, or the browser being open at all. They only depend on the browsers background thread to run, which usually always runs when the client runs.

Comment: The issue is that when on website, the service worker doesn't show the notification. I need to add an event handler on my website to show it.